# linux: redirect user prompt to /dev/null

Tags: linux, shell

Is it possible to prevent a shell command from interacting with user?

For example when I try to unzip a file and the destination directory has size limits, I got y/n prompt.

```
unzip my_file.zip -d /var/tmp/my_dir

write error (disk full?).  Continue? (y/n)
```

Is it possible to terminate the shell command immediately by sending all its prompt to /dev/nul?

Comment: You could do `unzip my_file.zip -d /var/tmp/my_dir < /dev/null` to make `unzip` read input from `/dev/null`, but minitech’s solution is better.

Comment: The < /dev/null is exactly what I was looking for. Please post it as answer and I will accept it.

One more question:
How Can I disable the password prompt? For example I want to clone a git repository, but want fail if it asks for password. I tried dev/null but this doesn't work:

git clone https://my_login@my_gitrep.git < /dev/null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `unzip` read input from `/dev/null` by redirecting its standard input:

```
unzip my_file.zip -d /var/tmp/my_dir < /dev/null
```

Another way to do this is with `cat`:

```
cat /dev/null | unzip my_file.zip -d /var/tmp/my_dir
```

That is slightly less efficient, since it starts another process (`cat`), but it’s perhaps easier to read. There are [endless arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) about whether using `cat` in this way is a bad idea.

If a program asks for a password and input file redirection doesn’t stop it from prompting you, then it gets trickier. Programs sometimes open your terminal directly using `/dev/tty`, rather than relying on standard input and output. In that case, you can use `expect` to send input to the program. I don’t know how to use `expect`, so I can’t provide a sample script. Or you can see if there is a way to prevent your program from asking for a password.

Comment: I asked why redirection doesn’t seem to work on password prompts on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171835/how-does-ssh-prompt-for-a-password-when-all-input-and-output-is-redirected).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `yes n` to answer “no” to every prompt:

```
yes n | unzip my_file.zip -d /var/tmp/my_dir
```